# Selenium webdriver wait for every action

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can I make selenium webdriver to wait for its every action execution "by default"? For example, set any "default wait time" to make it try to click every element 10 times every 500 ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it quite fussy for wait times, ended up installing webdriverIO to work with it, you can set timeout with that.

Theres this post about the different imeouts if its any use:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/what-is-seleniums-default-timeout-for-page-loading

Comment: Thanks, I found python examples: 

`$driver->manage()->timeouts()->pageLoadTimeout(30);
$driver->manage()->timeouts()->setScriptTimeout(30);`